# How to use the data of hidden columns in ag grid to create cross filter chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to create a cross filter chart based on data in the grid using Ag Grid library.

According to the example given in the documentation https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/integrated-charts-api-cross-filter-chart/#example-simple-cross-filter, if I hide the `sales` column using `hide:true` the cross filter chart get disappeared.
I understood that since the data is not avaliable in the grid after hiding the column, the chart gets disappeared.

So, is there any way like I can hide the column from the grid at the same time use the hidden column data to create crossFilterChart?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [suppressColumnsToolPanel](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/tool-panel-columns/#reference-columns-suppressColumnsToolPanel). Set to true if you do not want this column or group to appear in the Columns Tool Panel. You can then use the data from the column to create the cross-filter chart.

**columnDefs**

```
columnDefs: [
  { ...field: 'sales', suppressColumnsToolPanel: true }
]
```

**crossFilterChart**

```
gridOptions.api.crossFilterChart({
  dimensions: [
    {
      ...,
      filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
      ...,
      column: 'sales'
    }
    ...,
  ]
});
```

Comment: Is there any solution if we want to hide the column and still want the chart to work?